# Is there anything out there that will automatically notify me of failed Windows backups?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-backup

In the past, I have had backups fail due to a lack of hard drive space on the destination drive (among other reasons) and the only way I found out about them was through a gut feeling that I should check the Windows Backup & Restore Center.

I know that in Windows XP, the backup software created an entry in the event log each time the software tried to create a backup (and I even wrote a piece of software that notified me when a backup failed).

Is there any software package out there that will monitor the event log for failed backups and notify me if a backup fails? The software should be smart enough to send me an e-mail if there's a network connection available and notify me when I log in to the computer if a network connection doesn't appear in a few days (else, I might end with losing an entire week's worth of backups!).

Context:

- Source: Windows Vista computer
- Destination: External drive enclosure with a Seagate drive
- Software: Windows Backup & Restore

Comment: Yep! Definitely on-topic here! Don't worry!

Comment: *My name is studiohack and I approve this post*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried it myself but maybe [EventLog Inspector](http://fileforum.betanews.com/detail/EventLog-Inspector/1229510768/1) is what you're looking for.

Comment: It does everything except notify me with a popup. :)